# Как отобразить математические символы HTML при помощи python

Tags: python, html, unicode

`samp('&#8721;')` 
в питоне использую такую запись, но в HTML попадает
`<samp>&amp;#8721;</samp>`
Как исправить так, чтобы & не изменялся?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос <https://qna.habr.com/q/316456>

Comment: По указанной ссылке решение такое: str.replace("&amp;", "&");  В моем случае нужно будет заменять amp в переменной типа document. Как это можно сделать?